# intellij incorrectly saying no beans of type found for autowired repository

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, annotations, autowired

I have created a simple unit test but IntelliJ is incorrectly highlighting it red. marking it as an error

No beans?

[image]

As you can see below it passes the test? So it must be Autowired?

[image]

Comment: IntelliJ sometimes gives false positive autowire errors. For example in Spring Boot applications where a lot of the configuration is hidden behind EnableAutoConfiguration. There is an open issue for that. Other cause might be incorrectly configured Spring facet. What I usually do in these situations is lowering the inspection severity so that it's less obtrusive ...

Comment: This issue happened to me because I was mixing JUnit 4/Junit 5/Jupiter, for my @Test annotation. Switching them to Jupiter solved the autowire errors.

Comment: I'm on IntelliJ 2021.2.3 and this is still happening.

Comment: Still happening IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 (Ultimate Edition). Quite frustrating.

Comment: Still happening IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Ultimate Edition), in my specific case it is a @Service annotated class I use in a test and using @Autowired(required = false) locally as a workaround because tests run fine

Comment: Still happening on IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2 (Ultimate Edition), Build #IU-233.13135.103, built on December 19, 2023.

Context: 
@ Service
@ RequiredArgsConstructor
public class S3Service implements FileService {
    private final AmazonS3Client awsS3Client;

awsS3Client being the bean not found despite 
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;

Answer (score 290, accepted):

I had this same issue when creating a *Spring Boot* application using their `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. This annotation represents `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` according to the [spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html).

As expected, the new annotation worked properly and my application ran smoothly but, **Intellij** kept complaining about unfulfilled `@Autowire` dependencies. As soon as I changed back to using `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` separately, the errors ceased. It seems **Intellij 14.0.3** (and most likely, earlier versions too) is not yet configured to recognise the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

For now, if the errors disturb you that much, then revert back to those three separate annotations. Otherwise, ignore **Intellij**...your dependency resolution is correctly configured, since your test passes.

Always remember...

> Man is always greater than machine.

Comment: The issue is fixed now with newer versions of Intellij (checked on 2017.1)

Comment: I am still getting it with 2017.2, and it is the paid for ultimate license.

Comment: I am getting it with 2017.2 and SprintBootTest outer class and SpringBootApplication static inner class as per Spring Cloud Stream testing example: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/_testing.html

Comment: Does replacing `@SpringBootApplication` with the three separate annotations (`@Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan`) resolve the issue?

Comment: For more recent versions of IntelliJ (e.g. 2017) you have to enable the Spring Data plugin and then you don't need any of the above workarounds. There's another answer below that tells you how to do that.

Comment: I used @EnableAutoConfiguration to address it.

Comment: With IntelliJ 2018.2, using Spring Boot 2.0.5 and `@SpringBootApplication` I was receiving this error. I followed the advice of @Jaõs Matos by using the `scanBasePackages` parameter to `@SpringBootApplication` and specified the package/namespaces that should be scanned.

Comment: With IntelliJ 2018.1, I had `@SpringBootApplication` and was also receiving the error. It ended up being a problem with intelliJ's context not including the new configuration file where the `@Bean` was defined. After [including the new config in my context](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.1/spring-support.html?utm_content=2018.1&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_campaign=IU#spring-file-set), the error went away

Comment: Same issue with version 2020.1.

Comment: I am using Intellij 2020.1 and I get the same no beans found error.  Still trying to figure out how to get it working.  When I add a @Repository annotation to my DAO object, it seems to remove that error.  But my database connectivity doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Still with IntelliJ 2020.1, Spring boot 2 and @SpringBootTest

Comment: Same in 2020.3, Spring Boot 2.3.7, Kotlin 1.4.21, for @Autowired
    lateinit var embeddedKafka: EmbeddedKafkaBroker

Comment: In IntellijIDEA right clic and check > Mark Directory As > Test source.

Comment: Same here, version 2021.1.2 Ultimate Edition

Comment: THis solve the problem and the reference is below:-
https://www.programmersought.com/article/26636013309/
@ Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder){
        return builder.build();
    }
 
    @ Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

Comment: Great advice to ignore IntelliJ!

Comment: exists in 2022.1 Ultimate Edition

Comment: Same in 2021.1.4 Ultimate Edition

Comment: Sad to say this still happens in 2022.2 Ultimate Edition

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-281454/Could-not-autowire.-No-beans-of-XXX-type-found-IntelliJ-2021.2.3-Spring-2.5.6

Comment: Works for me in 2022.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Still present the error for me with [IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)]

Comment: Added 3 annotations to root configuration file: `Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` explicitly, and all those warnings disappeared.

Comment: I got the same error also in IntelliJ 2023.2. Ultimate. However, the error was presented only in Tests so I switched from @SpringBootTest to your suggested anotations and it works. Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed this in my project. I am working with 2023.1.3 (Ultimate Edition). It happens when I create a constructor in a `@Configuration` class. Does not complain with `@Service`.

Answer (score 100):

Add Spring annotation `@Repository` over the repository class.

I know it should work without this annotation. But if you add this, IntelliJ will not show error.

```
@Repository
public interface YourRepository ...
...
```

If you use Spring Data with extending `Repository` class it will be conflict packages. Then you must indicate packages directly.

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
...

@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public interface YourRepository extends Repository<YourClass, Long> {
    ...
}
```

And next you can autowired your repository without errors.

```
@Autowired
YourRepository yourRepository;
```

It probably is not a good solution (I guess you are trying to register repository twice). But work for me and don't show errors.

Maybe in the new version of IntelliJ can be fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137023

Comment: According to this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148113 it is fixed in version 16... (holds breath)

Comment: @Component also seems to work.  Looks like one just needs to force the interface / class to be scanned

Comment: You don't need to add @Repository anymore. Just on Spring Data plugin.

Comment: Three years later and it's broken again

Comment: I used /@Mapper for my mapper interface (mybatis). IDEA throw this warning. I changed it to /@Repository the warning gone.

Comment: Still same error in 2020.3.1 (Kotlin with default parameter value, runs fine but IntelliJ displays an error)

Answer (score 44):

Sometimes you are required to indicate where @ComponentScan should scan for components. You can do so by passing the packages as parameter of this annotation, e.g:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"path.to.my.components","path.to.my.othercomponents"})
```

However, as already mentioned, @SpringBootApplication annotation replaces @ComponentScan, hence in such cases you must do the same:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"path.to.my.components","path.to.my.othercomponents"})
```

At least in my case, Intellij stopped complaining.

Comment: This is definitely the better, cleaner solution, and can confirm that this removed the warning. Thanks!

Comment: In my case I had `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.a.b, com.a.c"})`  and although the app worked fine, intellij didn't like it. Changing to `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.a.b", "com.a.c"})` fixed for me!

Comment: This is by far the best solution, since it's portable between IDEs and clearly communicates developer intent.

Comment: I'm using ultimate 2019.3.1 spring boot 2.2.1 and java 11.0.4. The problem still exists in unit test files.

Comment: what @GriffoGoes suggested fixed my problem, since i was ussing a multi module structure, that was my best solution

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Clearly stating the root cause and solution.

Comment: thanks! It helped! I noticed that my package was wrong but Idea just marked it with yellow color!

Answer (score 43):

My version of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (2016.3.4 Build 163) seems to support this. The trick is that you need to have enabled the Spring Data plugin.

[image]

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well -- It seems like this may be the real issue for anyone who otherwise has their code setup correctly!

Comment: Doesn't work in 2017.2.7. Plugin is enabled, but the warning is still present.

Comment: Worked for me in iJ Ultimate 2018.2.5.

Comment: Worked for intellij idea ultimate 2020

Comment: Upvoting this, worked like a charm in Idea Ultimate 2020.2

Comment: This doesn't work even after enabling the plugin

Answer (score 39):

I always solve this problem doing de following..
***Settings>Inspections>Spring Core>Code*** than you shift from error to warning the severity option

[image]

Comment: I went with this solution until a fix is made on Spring: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-182912

Comment: In IntelliJ 2021.3 this setting has been renamed to `Incorrect injection point autowiring in Spring bean components`.

Answer (score 26):

I am using spring-boot 2.0, and intellij 2018.1.1 ultimate edition and I faced the same issue.

I solved by placing @EnableAutoConfiguration in the main application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class App{
/**/
}
```

Comment: This also "works" for me, but then intellij complains:

`Redundant declaration: @SpringBootApplication already applies @EnableAutoConfiguration`

¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This is Redundant declaration: @SpringBootApplication already applies `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

Comment: @EnableAutoConfiguration on the class where IntelliJ complaining fixed the issue for me too.

Comment: @Arefe this is redundant but this fix the "autowired not found" error. It seems to be an intellij bug.... I've put this annotation on another class than the `@SpringBootApplication` to fix all errors

Answer (score 23):

Check if you missed @Service annotation in your service class, that was the case for me.

Comment: This was the case for me. make sure we have '@Service' in the service class and '@Repository' in the repository class.

Answer (score 13):

Configure application context and all will be ok.

[image]

Comment: I had a service in multimodule project, adding Spring Application Context to the module in question has resolved the issue

Comment: I think in my case the problem was that I had two @SpringBootApplication annotations in one project (one for a dataloader and one for the real project).

I followed your advice and defined two different application contexts explicitly as you showed it in your screenshot and then the errors were gone.

Thanks!

Comment: It's useful to add the application context file in the Project setting -> Facets

Answer (score 12):

Have you checked that you have used `@Service` annotation on top of your service implementation?
It worked for me.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserServices {}
```

Comment: removing it worked for me :O

Answer (score 12):

Use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation with `@Component` at class level. It will resolve this problem.

For example:

```java
@Component
@EnableAutoConfiguration  
public class ItemDataInitializer  {

    @Autowired
    private ItemReactiveRepository itemReactiveRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Putting `@Component` or `@configuration` in your bean config file seems to work, ie something like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyApplicationContext {
    @Bean
    public DirectoryScanner scanner() {
        return new WatchServiceDirectoryScanner("/tmp/myDir");
    }
}

@Component
public class MyApplicationContext {
    @Bean
    public DirectoryScanner scanner() {
        return new WatchServiceDirectoryScanner("/tmp/myDir");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

simple you have to do 2 steps

1. add hibernate-core dependency
2. change `@Autowired` to `@Resource`.

```
==>> change @Autowired to  @Resource
```

Comment: Explain your answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to make any change to you code just to make your IDE happy. I have solved it by adding all components to the Spring facet.

1. Create a group with name "Service, Processors and Routers" or any name you like;
2. Remove and recreate "Spring Application Context" use the group you created previously as a parent.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As long as your tests are passing you are good, hit `alt + enter` by taking the cursor over the error and inside the submenu of the first item you will find `Disable Inspection` select that

Comment: Thanks. By the way is there a way to see all changes made that are not default in one view in IntelliJ Settings (so you know what you have changed)?

Comment: Seems to be the only solution for me to get rid of the annoying red lines. I could just ignore it, but it always catches my attention and makes me feel like I need to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

I am using this annotation to hide this error when it appears in IntelliJ v.14:

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
```

Comment: When autowired into a constructor it is `@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")`

Answer (score 5):

For me the solution was to place `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in the Application class under the `@SpringBootApplication` its going to underline it because its redundant. Delete it and voila all you warnings regarding missing beans are vanished! Silly Spring...

Comment: I was so desperate I actually tried this :-) I needed to add the bean to my CoreApplication class

Answer (score 4):

And one last piece of important information - add the `ComponentScan` so that the app knows about the things it needs to wire.  This is not relevant in the case of this question.  However if no `@autowiring` is being performed at all then this is likely your solution.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "some_package",
})
public class someService {
```

Comment: This makes sense and did the trick for me. Why turn off warnings? The warnings should work as expected!

Answer (score 4):

This and another kind of "Could not autowire. No Beans of ..." can be solved by installing the plugin, in my case was JobBuilderFactory from Spring Batch.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue in Spring Boot application. The application utilizes Feign (HTTP client synthetizing requests from annotated interfaces). Having interface `SomeClient` annotated with `@FeignClient`, Feign generates runtime proxy class implementing this interface. When some Spring component tries to autowire bean of type `SomeClient`, Idea complains no bean of type `SomeClient` found since no real class actually exists in project and Idea is not taught to understand `@FeignClient` annotation in any way.

Solution: annotate interface `SomeClient` with `@Component`. (In our case, we don't use `@FeignClient` annotation on `SomeClient` directly, we rather use metaannotation `@OurProjectFeignClient` which is annotated `@FeignClient` and adding `@Component` annotation to it works as well.)

Comment: Yes, adding `@Component` to the interface solves the issue. But I think this is not the correct way... In my opinion this is a bug in IntelliJ IDEA or to be not so hard IntelliJ IDEA is not ready for newer Feign versions. It works without `@Component` in erlier feign versions (where the `@FeignClient` annotation was in `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign` instead of `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign` - maybe this is the cause of the issue?). Have you found any further details (maybe a bug ticket) for this?

Comment: No, I haven't, though my case (which didn't work without `@Component`) is `@FeignClient` from `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign`) package.

Comment: Issue at JetBrains bug tracker is here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168155

Answer (score 3):

in my Case, the Directory I was trying to @Autowired was not at the same level,

after setting it up at the same structure level, the error disappeared

hope it can helps some one!

Answer (score 3):

just add below two annotations to your POJO.

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class YourClass {
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: Adding @ComponentScan worked for me. Thank you. I am using version 2020.3.1

Answer (score 3):

As most synchronisation errors between IntelliJ (IDE) and development environments.

Specially if you have automated tests or build that pass green all the way through.

**Invalidate Cache and Restart** solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this issue in my spring boot application was to open the spring application context and adding the class for the missing autowired bean manually!

(access via Project Structure menu or spring tool window... edit "Spring Application Context")

So instead of SpringApplicationContext just containing my ExampleApplication spring configuration it also contains the missing Bean:

SpringApplicationContext:

- ExampleApplication.java
- MissingBeanClass.java

et voilà: The error message disappeared!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to still be a bug in the latest IntelliJ and has to do with a possible caching issue?

If you add the @Repository annotation as mk321 mentioned above, save, then remove the annotation and save again, this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is add

`@ComponentScan("package/include/your/annotation/component")`  in `AppConfiguration.java`.

Since I think your `AppConfiguraion.java`'s package is **deeper** than your annotation component (@Service, @Component...)'s package,

such as `"package/include/your/annotation/component/deeper/config"`.

Comment: @ComponentScan("package.include.your.annotation.component") !

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in my application.
When I added annotations incorrect highliting dissapeared.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {...})
```

Comment: only for test packages!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes - in my case that is - the reason is a wrong import. I accidentally imported

```
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service
```

instead of

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
```

by blindly accepting the first choice in Idea's suggested imports. Took me a few minutes the first time it happend :-)

Answer (score 2):

I just had to use @EnableAutoConfiguration to address it, however this error had no functional impact.

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved by placing @EnableAutoConfiguration on spring boot application main class.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Add your main class to IntelliJ  Spring Application Context, for example Application.java

`File` -> `Project Structure..`

left side:
Project Setting -> Modules

right side: find in your package structure
`Spring` and add `+` `Application.java`

Comment: It is equal to U.V. answer

Answer (score 2):

in my situation my class folder was in wrong address so check if your class is in correct package.

Comment: Yes my kotlin file didn't have at all `package` on top that was the issue

Answer (score 2):

I got this error out of *Repository* layer. I missed a simple **@Component** for the class. This could be a problem. Add this annotation **@Component** on top of the corresponding Implementation class

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to make this work is the following code:

```
@ComponentScan
public class PriceWatchTest{

    @Autowired
    private PriceWatchJpaRepository priceWatchJpaRepository;
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add the annotation `@Service`  to your Repository class and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and solved it using "Invalidate Caches..." under the File menu.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the issue. Just use

```
@SpringBootTest

@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

annotation with the test class.

Answer (score 1):

I removed this code. no more errors

[image]

---

Other way to check:
add the annotation @Service to your Repository class and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

As for intelliJ version 2021.2.3 (Ultimate Edition) I changed "incorrect injection point autowiring in spring bean compontents to warning which works for me[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Autowired(required = false)
will shut intellij up

Comment: That will change the behaviour of your application. Unless you really want the bean to be optional, don't do it just because IDEA has a bug.

Comment: Indeed, as mentioned in the original question, field injection is utilized solely for testing purposes. It's appropriate to use it in this context, so there shouldn't be any issues with employing it specifically for tests.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to run your tests without actually activating your **WebEnvironment**.

The solution is quite simple, just add `@SpringBootTest` annotation with a required config.

Here is an example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) // Run the server for testing.
public class mockTest {

    @Autowired
    // Should work now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, A Feign oriented project that successfully ran with Eclipse could not run in InteliJ.
When started the application, InteliJ complained about the Feign client I tried to inject to the serviceImpl layer saying:
field personRestClient (my Feign client) in ... required a bean of type ... that could not be found.
Consider defining a bean of type '....' in your configuration.

I wasted a long time trying to understand what is wrong.
I found a solution (for InteliJ) which I do not completely understand:

1. Alt Shift F10 (or run menu)
2. Select 'Edit configuration'
3. In configuration window, Check the checkbox 'include dependencies with 
   "Provided" scope'
4. Run your application

Or choose Eclipse :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the package of your bean is written correctly

```
//Check if this is written right 
package com.package1.package2.package3


import ...

@Service
class ServiceX {

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @AutoConfigureMockMvc for test class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing mybatis plugin in IDEA. When I installed Mybatis Plugin, it disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my Intellij IDEA version to 2022.2.3 like below:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)
>
> Build #IU-222.4345.14
>
> Runtime version: 17.0.4.1+7-b469.62 aarch64

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.x.y") in your desired place. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know, seven year later but this can help to others.
This is my Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public abstract class ApiTest
```

Everything's fine. but the problem was my folders, for example:

If you have the next structure -> main.java.com.api.service

So it's the same for the test  -> test.java.com.api.service

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@ComponentScan` with `basePackages` attribute to scan related bean like this :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.xxxx.yyyy.reportdistributor"})
```

Answer (score 0):

It may happen because you didn't add spring web dependency so the IDE considers your application as Spring application not Spring boot

Answer (score 0):

i get the same error while i was using my first springbootapp
but I solved with :

1. @Configuration
   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   in java class that I used to call the implemented class
   2.@Repository in the interface

but if I removed it I got the same error again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ Idea 2021.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)

I have such a service

```
import org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties;

@Service
public class MyVeryBestService {

    private final BuildProperties buildProperties;

    @Autowired
    public MyVeryBestService(BuildProperties buildProperties) {
        this.buildProperties = buildProperties;
    }
    //some other code
}
```

Application failed to start with this error

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in MyVeryBestService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' that could not be found
```

I execute maven goal clean and go to **File -> Repair IDE...** and it helps. I've tried **Invalidate Caches...** but it doesn't help.

Answer (score -22):

I encountered this issue too, and resolved it by the removing Spring Facet:

- File -> Project Structure
- Select `Facets`
- Remove Spring

Good luck!