# Intellij reports error 'cannot autwire beans of type `HttpServletRequest` type found'

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA (2017.2.6) reports an error in the autowired constructor of one of my services, that it cannot autowire `HttpServletRequest`. However, my application is working fine and the request is autowired perfectly fine. Could this be a bug in IntelliJ or is there some reason the autowiring works despite there being no `@Bean` being defined for it?

Note, I don't want tot suppress these errors because they work correctly for all other autowired beans.

My constructor looks like this:

```
@Autowired
public MyOtherService(HttpServletRequest request, @Lazy MyService myService) {
  this.myService = myService;
  this.currentRequest = request;
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889970/intellij-incorrectly-saying-no-beans-of-type-found-for-autowired-repository

Comment: @ddepablo That is relevant for user-defined spring component stereotypes.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved in the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA (2017.3)

See: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2017-3