# JUnit & IntelliJ: Could not autowire. No beans of type found

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit

I'm trying to run a basic unit test on the code in this GitHub repository [found here](https://github.com/microservices-practical/microservices-v1)

The test in MultiplicationServiceTest fails because of the following error:

```
Caused by:     org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'microservices.book.multiplication.service.MultiplicationService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
... 28 more
```

The IDE I'm using is IntelliJ and from some Googling I see that it often reports an error when @Autowire is used in test cases.  The error is affecting the multiplicationService variable in the MultiplicationServiceTest class and I'm unsure why.  I've tried tagging the MultiplicationService interface with @Repository but this doesn't resolve the error.  Any help is appreciated.

MultiplicationServiceTest:

```
package microservices.book.multiplication.service;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

import microservices.book.multiplication.domain.Multiplication;
import microservices.book.multiplication.service.MultiplicationService;
import microservices.book.multiplication.service.RandomGeneratorService;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MultiplicationServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private RandomGeneratorService randomGeneratorService;

    @Autowired
    private MultiplicationService multiplicationService;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

    }

}
```

MultiplicationService:

```
package microservices.book.multiplication.service;

import microservices.book.multiplication.domain.Multiplication;

public interface MultiplicationService {

    Multiplication createRandomMultiplication();

}
```

Multiplication:

```
package microservices.book.multiplication.domain;

public class Multiplication {

    private int factorA;
    private int factorB;
    private int result;

    public Multiplication(int factorA, int factorB, int result) {
        this.factorA = factorA;
        this.factorB = factorB;
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

SocialMultiplicationApplication:

```
package microservices.book.multiplication;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SocialMultiplicationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialMultiplicationApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I found the answer on another StackOverflow link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889970/intellij-incorrectly-saying-no-beans-of-type-found-for-autowired-repository)

Comment: Please mention this at the beginning of your question to make it easier to find the solution without needing to read the comments.