# Can you @Autowired a @MessageGateway into a RestController

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-integration

I am curious if it is possible to @Autowired a @MessageGateway into a rest controller

Bellow is a .java file:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfiguration {


    @MessagingGateway
    public interface ScheduleGateway {

        @Gateway( requestChannel = "schedule.input" )
        OptimizedSchedule optimize( scheduleRequest request );

    }
```

And the RestController is a .kt file

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/optimize")
class OptimizationController(val myEventRepo: eventRepository,
                             val myDataTransformer: myDataTransform,
                             val myOtherDataTransformer: myOtherDataTransformer,
                             val gateway: ScheduleGateway)
```

I am getting the error message

'Could not autowire. No beans of '' type found

I found this article online but I couldn't get their suggestion to work.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/21

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please, share more stack trace on the matter. It is not clear from your point what exactly bean cannot be injected.

Comment: You don't appear to have `@IntegrationComponentScan`, which is needed to detect `@MessagingGateway` and create an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889970/intellij-incorrectly-saying-no-beans-of-type-found-for-autowired-repository) They wrote almost all the wrong things you can have for this error. In my case, @EnableAutoConfiguration was missing in the main class. Also, it might be due to @ComponentScan.