# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring

I run a Spring boot project and received the error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-11-23 15:34:48.542 ERROR 10579 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/example/config/multitenant/HibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

Apparently, the error comes from the class and it can't Autowire the JpaProperties:

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            DataSource dataSource,
            MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
            CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl
    ) {
        //Properties related to MultiTenancyStrategy Schema
        Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap = new HashMap<>(jpaProperties.getProperties());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);

        //Properties related to MultiTenancyStrategy Database
        //jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        //jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        //jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);

        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.example*");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(
            value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE,
            proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor simpleNativeJdbcExtractor = new SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor() {
            @Override
            public Connection getNativeConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                con.setSchema(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
                return super.getNativeConnection(con);
            }

            @Override
            public Connection getNativeConnectionFromStatement(Statement stmt) throws SQLException {
                return super.getNativeConnectionFromStatement(stmt);
            }
        };

        simpleNativeJdbcExtractor.setNativeConnectionNecessaryForNativeStatements(true);

        jdbcTemplate.setNativeJdbcExtractor(simpleNativeJdbcExtractor);

        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you using `Maven` or `Gradle`?

Comment: @TechGeek49 Its maven and can share the pom file

Comment: yeah sure. I would like to take a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889970/intellij-incorrectly-saying-no-beans-of-type-found-for-autowired-repository

Comment: Check the above link