# Cannot fix the error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've search in stackoverflow and many person got this error. I've tried all solution I got but no one works for me.
Below, there is my files and the stacktraces :

SecurityConfig.java

```
//Class contenant la configuration de la sécurité du projet
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

UserDetailsService.java :

```
@Data
@Builder
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = null;
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        User user = userOptional
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No user " +
                        "Found with username : " + username));

        return new org.springframework.security
                .core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                user.isEnabled(), true, true,
                true, getAuthorities("USER"));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String role) {
        return singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
}
```

Stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@5c3924fd of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@5c3924fd of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@7d7a8d23 of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:69) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter$CompositeObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:118) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter.postProcess(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:79) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@7d7a8d23': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:420) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:65) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.doAfterPropertiesSet(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:85) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:119) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
```

There are many error here, but the main error i got here is the first. I've try to @Override the Security class and delete the inheritance WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter bhut it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that is a bit suspicious is that the UserDetailsService is not autowired, therefore

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Autowired
   private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

Can help you. The second thing that I find you can get rid off is the definition of the AuthenticationManager Bean, you are already using a the AuthenticationManagerBuilder. Try to remove also this code

```
@Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

And last but not least, your class UserDetailService should not implement the UserDetail Interface, they are two different concepts, the Service fetches Users, therefore implementing methods like isEnabled() or isAccountNonExpired() are meaningless.

Comment: Currently, a part of you answer help me to solve this solution. When I've tried to put the annotation ```@Autowired```, I got an error. I'm using  ```@SpringBootApplication``` annotation. This annotation represents ```@Configuration```, ```@EnableAutoConfiguration``` and ```@ComponentScan``` according to the spring reference. As soon as I changed back to using ```@Configuration```, ```@EnableAutoConfiguration``` and ```@ComponentScan``` separately, the errors ceased.

Comment: Here where I got the solution og ```@Autowired``` problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889970/intellij-incorrectly-saying-no-beans-of-type-found-for-autowired-repository