# objectMapper not configured automatically

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, jackson, autowired, objectmapper

I'm having below spring boot application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT);
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

        return converter;
    }

}
```

in my intelliJ IDE, it's showing warning in objectMapper param as below

```
Could not autowire. no beans of 'ObjectMapper' type found.
```

Based on my understanding, objectMapper will autowire here automatically. and even I didn't got any error while running application. able to up the application.

Not sure, why intelliJ showing this warning.

Help me to find this and add/correct me if I missed anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [intellij incorrectly saying no beans of type found for autowired repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889970/intellij-incorrectly-saying-no-beans-of-type-found-for-autowired-repository)

Comment: What Spring and IDE versions do you use? `Help | About` I can't reproduce the problem in the 2022.1 version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download  (https://prnt.sc/BDNj4Hh58ijr)

Comment: Are you using ObjectMapper from `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` dependency?

Comment: using from com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

Comment: What Spring and IDE versions do you use? `Help | About` Please check if it works in the latest build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Comment: Using spring boot 2.7 and intelliJ 2021.2

Comment: Please check if the problem reproduces in 2022.2.1 from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Comment: not able to reproduce in 2022.1.3